# Using non dimension data in KPI (SSAS Cube)

Tags: ssas, kpi

I am trying to create KPIs for performance of students in each department and also across university.

The goal of average pass percentage of whole university is in a OLTP table and each departments have their own goal of average pass percentage in department OLTP table.

For department KPI, I could use the goal of average pass perecentage defined in department OLTP table in goal expression, because departement table is also dimension table; where as for university KPI, the goal of average pass percentage in university OLTP table is not accessible(via dimension table), because university table is not a dimension table. How can I access the goal of average pass percentage of university in goal expression of university KPI?

Comment: Are you using the OLTP database as a datasource in the SSAS project or do you make the a mid-tier DataWarehouse using ELT? Seems like the first case is true. Why don't you make the univercity a dimension? How will you be able to access data, that is without making them a part of your solution?

Comment: I am using mid-tier data warehouse using ETL. University cannot be a dimension because, all the students belong to one university. Is there are a way to make a table that is not related to fact table(students scores fact table here) as a dimension table?